# <dvt:barChart> Bar chart component is taking considerably more time to load when it has more than 500 data in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

Bar chart component is taking considerably more time to load when it has more than 500 data. If the fetch size is reduced to 400 then it works fine. Is this the issue with the component? Or how do I tune the performance of this component.

Thanks